# TradingView Strategy Tester Profit Calculation formula

Tags: pine-script

How does TradingView's Strategy Tester really calculate the profit?

I read [an article](https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000561856-how-are-strategy-tester-report-values-calculated-and-what-do-they-mean/) in their Help center. It states that they calculate it by `(close rate - open rate)`.

#### My attempt

- Initial balance = $300
- Fee = 0.1%

In my case, for the first order, it would've been `3.6307 - 3.5487 = 0.082`. $0.082 is definitely not $6.28.

The Profit % however matches, even tho I didn't include the fees. `profit % = (close rate - open_rate) / open_rate * 100 = (3.6307 - 3.5487) / 3.5487 * 100 = 2.3107053287119226759094879815144` (matches)

How did they receive $6.28 profit?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, lets calculate your Gross Profit:

```
Profit is :(3.6307-3.5487) * 84 = 6.888 
//Sell Price - Buy price times the contracts you traded

//Commission is 0.1% of the value traded; that means the commission you pay is 

(3.6307 + 3.5487) * 84* 0.1% = 0.6031........ 
//I combined calculation for buy side and sell side here

Net profit = 6.888 - 0.6031 = 6.2849 (appx)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! What about the contracts, how are they calculated? As far as I can see they are the coin quantity traded. `300 / 3.5487 * (1 - 0.001) = 84.453461831093076337813847324372`

Comment: I guess so... I thought you might have some formula to calculate the quantity since it kept changing, but it seems the strategy is using the entire capital for trading. 
Don't forget to mark it as answer,

Comment: One more question, how did you know how to calculate it? Is there a link which gives additional information, because what they did at https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000561856-how-are-strategy-tester-report-values-calculated-and-what-do-they-mean/ is very unclear and I'm now struggling with profit %

Comment: I just tried to calculate it manually, and the answer matched. I'll try to find something for profit %

Comment: I think profit %, is just your total profit/ initial capital * 100

Comment: Hey, can you show me how you used multiple exit conditions, I tried to use 2 strategy.exit and it rendered 1 one of them untriggered while one worked perfectly

Comment: A friend did it, but here it is: https://pastebin.com/3W1R7VTi

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped